# Overlapping table view scrolls tableView behind it

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, uiview

Basically I have a compound view in my storyboard:

- a `UIView` with inputs. Let's call it **View1**
- container view displays `tableView` controller (**View2**)

Works fine.

I have a small issue when another displayed `tableview` from `UIView` overlaps the bottom **View2** with its own results. Only cells that stays within the bound of the **View1** can be interacted with and selected. The part of the `tableView` (autocomplete results) that actually overlaps **View2** (and it looks like it is on top) scrolls the **View2**..

[image]

I already tried referencing View1 and setting `View1.layer.zPosition` to a higher value. It wouldn't help..

Any suggestions?

If this requires modifying the code Swift syntax is preferred over obj-c

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that the tableview with the autocomplete results is added to view1. And so it only receive touches sent to it. If you select clipSubviews on the view1 you'll see that your autocomplete results tableView will be cut to the bounds of the view1 1.

Try to add the autocomplete results tableView to the self.view(main view of the View Controller). This way it will be above both view1 and view2 and it will receive all the touches that come on this tableview

Comment: You're right. I place the autocomplete tableView one level up the hierarchy and adjusted its top height so it appeared always below each textfield. It totally works now! Thank you.